# Get color from distance

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was playing around with JavaScript/canvas and I want my objects color to depend on the distance to its center from current mouse position.This is my current function that gets color every `mousemove` event:

```
function getColorFromDistance(node1,node2){
    var dist = getDist(node1,node2); //Getting distance;
    var cl = (Math.round(255/dist*255)).toString(16); //this needs to be a propper formula
    return "#" + cl + cl + cl; //converting to hex
}
```

Currently I get a blink effect when the distance gets 255.
I need a way to get the colors strength be depended on the distance, so that the further mouse is away from object the more its darken and when mouse is on the objects center its fully white.Well you get the idea.I just need the formula

Comment: If you would like a colored version you may check my codePen http://codepen.io/kmlzjc/pen/oLrkNb, it is not perfect, needs some adjustments, but I think it is mainly what you wanted. It used css hls to make things easier to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula would be calculate the distance between the two points and get a percentage based on the maximum value (width of canvas/window)

```js
//this would need to be recalulated on resize, but not doing it for demo
var targetElem = document.querySelector("div.x span");
    box = targetElem.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = box.left + box.width/2,
    y = box.top + box.height/2,
    winBox = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
    maxD = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(winBox.width/2, 2) + Math.pow(winBox.height/2, 2));
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function (evt) {
  var diffX = Math.abs(evt.pageX-x),
      diffY = Math.abs(evt.pageY-y),
      distC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(diffX, 2) + Math.pow(diffY, 2)),
      strength = Math.ceil(255 - (distC/maxD*255)).toString(16),
      color = "#" + strength + strength + strength;
  targetElem.style.backgroundColor = color;      
});
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
div.x { position: absolute; top: 50%; left:50%; }
span { display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test</p>
<div class="x"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Work's as I wanted

Comment: The proportion of two distances does not change  when you square them. Calculating the square roots is redundant in your example just use the sum of the squares.